# How To Set "Account Operators" to AD User?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, account

For now I've got a script where I can see every user from my Active Directory who has the SID from AccountOperators (5-1-2-32-548) set and the ones who don't.

And now I want to that the user account without this SID, that they can be changed/edited from every other User with the SID set.

Not that they get the SID set.

Comment: What "property" are you talking about? Please describe in more detail what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Again, what are you talking about? By default the builtin group "Account Operators" should already have [`GENERIC_ALL` permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961985.aspx) on account objects. Please take a step back and describe what you want to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 2):

`Set-Acl` can set AD permissions just fine, but you don't want to set an ACL or SID. You want to add a user to the (builtin) domain group "Account Operators":

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Set-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Account Operators' -Members 'username'
```